# Does taking Ln of dependent variable improve assumptions of a multiple regression?

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, qq-plot, scatterplot

I have run two multiple regressions in R, one with average abundance as dependent variable, and one with log avg abundance as dependent variable. With the given plots, can we say one of the two regression meets assumptions better than the other? Log of Avg Abundance is on the right. Assumptions of concern include linear relationship, normal distribution, independence and Homoscedasticity.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us more about this "average abundance"? Is that a count variable originally? Do you have access to the raw data? I suspect you should use a GLM instead of OLS regression. Regarding independence: Do you have repeated measures? Is this time series data? Could there be any spatial dependence?

Comment: Please note: I've updated the plots since originally posting this question (I found mistakes in the others). Average abundance was originally counts over five years. I do have access to the raw data. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about statistics to know if I have repeated measures. If I understand what spatial dependence means, then I think the answer is yes. There are roughly 3000 routes along which I have data for species abundance and for the type of land surrounding that route. I'm trying to determine whether species abundance is effected by land use type in that area.

Comment: Keep your data as counts and fit a GLMM with a family appropriate for count data, e.g., Poisson. You should talk to a local statistician.